# Checkbox no me funciona en una tabla de paginacion

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo un `CheckBox` que no funciona cuando hago clic en las otras paginas de mi tabla, no me envía los parámetros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi código llamo de esta forma a la función.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que contiene tu método enviar_al_hacer_check() ?

Comment: seleciona los datos q voy a enviar a mi otra tabla mediante ajax

Comment: en la 1ra y 2da pagina si me funciona el checkbox  pero en mis demas paginas yano me funcionan .

Comment: @RonaldRios Imagino que los elementos de la tabla se crean dinámicamente por eso tu manejador de eventos no se dispara. Tienes que volver a ejecutar el código cada vez que cambies de página.

Comment: si pero como hago q se ejecute cada vez q voy a otra pagina de la tabla.Asi lo toy llamando                                                     enviar_al_hacer_check();
 $('.paginate_button').click(function(){enviar_al_hacer_check();});

Comment: @RonaldRios No haz puesto código del paginador así que no podría decirte. Yo sólo estoy especulando aquí pero podría ser la causa. Tienes que poner `$('botonpaginador').click()` y dentro llamar a la función `enviar_al_hacer_check()`. No te olvides tambien hacer otra función y poner `$('.enviar_check').off('change')` para eliminar los eventos que pudieran haberse quedado.

Comment: $('.paginate_button').click(function(){enviar_al_hacer_check();});  en esta parte lo pongo mi paginatebutton   y al otro lado mi funcion

Comment: @devconcept el codigo del paginador esta en javascript este es un proyecto que lo encontre en el internet y lo toy modificando es por eso

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html   lo hago como esto  :( ayudeme xfavor

Answer (score 1):

Buenas!

Creo que la solución de llamar a la función tantas veces como cambies de pagina no es buena solución, incluso puedes acumular los triggers y obtener varias llamadas a la misma función e ir creando una pila, vamos un posible desastre.

Una solución para esto es usar 'eventos burbujeantes' (no estoy seguro si se llamaba así). En un rápido resumen, consiste en adjuntarle este evento al documento directamente y buscar mediante el selector tu elemento, no importando si no tienes estos elementos aun en tu html y los inyectas/generas mas tarde, lanzara el evento igualmente.

Este es el código:

```
$(document).on('change', '.clase-selector', function(){
    // Tu funcion aqui
})
```

Comment: gracias @Webserveis por la correcion de faltas de ortografias. Con el teclado ingles en la oficina, no me es posible escribirlos. Cheers!

Comment: De nada, aquí estamos haciendo comunidad entre todos.

Comment: has probado esta solucion? si es que si, dinos si te funciona, en caso de que si, por favor puntua mi respuesta como correcta, si no, dinos que no funciona y lo revisamos @RonaldRios

Comment: @RonaldRios Has probado mi solucion???

Comment: si lo probé y sigue = :(